# `beforeEach` Behavior with Nested Tests in Intern

Tags: javascript, testing, intern

Just wondering how `beforeEach` works when you have nested functional tests in intern using the `object` interface. For example

```
registerSuite({
    name: 'Before Each Test Suite',
    beforeEach: function () {
        // parent beforeEach
    },
    'test one': function () {},
    'inner suite': {
        beforeEach: function () {
            // nested beforeEach
        },
        'test two': function () {},
        'test three': function () {}
    }
});
```

In this scenario I would expect the parent `beforeEach` to be called three times (once for each test) and the nested `beforeEach` to be called twice. However, in my testing, it appears that the parent `beforeEach` is only called twice. Once for `test one` and only once for `inner suite`. Am I missing something or is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, but it will change in the future since nobody else seems to expect it. See: https://github.com/theintern/intern/issues/67